# how to pass struct as parameter and memcpy it in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
   int a[3];
} A;

typedef struct
{
   int b;
} B;

typedef struct
{
    A a;
    B b;
} C;

void getC(C *c_p)
{
    C c;
    c.a.a[0] = 1;
    c.b.b = 1;
    memcpy(c_p, &c, sizeof(C));
}

int main()
{
    C *c;
    getC(c);
}
```

and it says the process returned, I really can not find the reason, I assume the memcpy part is not working, can anyone helps?

Comment: You haven't allocated memory for `c` in `main` to point to. You're `memcpy`ing to an uninitialised pointer, invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why would the process not return? It's not like you're doing anything which could stop it returning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in your `main`, where you pass an uninitialized pointer to `getC`. You should make it point to something, like this:

```
C c;
getC(&c);
```

or

```
C *c = malloc(sizeof(C));
getC(c);
...
free(c);
```

Moreover, you do not need to use `memcpy` with `struct`s - an assignment will work as well:

```
void getC(C *c_p)
{
    C c;
    c.a.a[0] = 1;
    c.b.b = 1;
    *c_p = c; // No memcpy
}
```

Comment: +1, I'd add another +1 for mentioning struct assignment if I could. :)